# What is the exact difference between native app and web app in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When we register an application in the Azure Active Directory for using graph api, I see there are two types of application Web application and Native application.

While creating web application there are two values requested  1. Sign-on URL and 2. App ID url. What is the use of these values ? Do we required real world url or just https://localhost:randomePort  enough ?

On the other hand while creating Native application, I can see only one required value 'Redirect URL'.

I can obtain access token for web application using REST call

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token

grant_type      client_credentials
client_id       (the client ID of the calling service application in the AD)
client secret   (the key configured in the calling service application in the AD)
resource        https://graph.windows.net
```

**But how can I obtain access token for native app using such REST call ? because there is not client secret for native appliction**

Coming to permissions, for the native app, I can see only delegated permissions option available while for web app I can see application permission as well as delegated permissions option.

One more thing, above REST call example authenticates application, How can I authenticate user using his credential using REST call ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Native applications are public clients in OAuth2 parlance. Those apps are meant to run on a device and aren't trusted to maintain a secret - hence, their entry in the directory does not have the corresponding property. Without a secret, there is no way to assert the identity of the app - hence such apps cannot gain app level permissions and the portal UX reflects that.
Conversely web apps are, again in OAuth2 parlance, confidential clients. They can get delegated tokens for their users, but they can also use client credentials to get tokens as themselves.
Native apps can obtain tokens for the user via the OAuth2 authorization grant. You can find a complete overview of all supported topologies at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/. Each scenario description point to more implementation oriented guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the information. One more thing, where can I get detailed information about 'application permissions' required on 'Windows Azure Active Directory' application to Update, Delete, Create objects using client web application. I think 'Read Directory data’ will be for reading object info, and 'Read and Write Directory data’ for update object, but for some web application it doesn't seems working

Comment: Hi Sagar, for information on the mapping between the different Applicatoin/Delegation permissions and the access you want to the Graph API please take a look at this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2015/10/06/new-graph-api-consent-permissions.aspx  

and this MSDN Post: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/graph-api-permission-scopes