# Showing Keep Me Signed In when requesting tokens from Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to show the Keep Me Signed In checkbox when logging a user into Active Directory via the login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantId].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize endpoints? When logging in via login.microsoftonline.com, the page will show the KMSI box, but it is missing on the oauth2 endpoints. See for example the two attached images.

[Login endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIys3.png)

[Authorize endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Nye.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the test, the **Keep me sign-in** is only work for the **web app**. If you developing the web app it should shows like figure below:
[image]

This is expected because that **Keep me signed in** uses the **cookies** to store the sign-in user info and the native client is not using the broswer.

If you have problem to keep the users sign-in for a long time, you may share the secnario and detail code you were developing.

Comment: Thanks Fei. We are doing an on-behalf-of flow from an Outlook add-in, that gets a token from AD and sends it to a web service we've set up, which then gets a token for Sharepoint using the token sent by the add-in. 

The add-in was set up as a native client, since it is all Javascript. I was going by the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054393/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-native-app-and-web-app-in-azure-active-dire when making that choice.

I've changed our client side app to the Web App type, and the KMSI box now appears.